# filter by is_active boolean field in django

Tags: python, django, filter

I want to have an `is_active` field for all the models in my application and when ever I create an api, I want to filter only the active ones and send the response. Is there a generic way to do this? As of now I am keeping a `boolean` field `is_active` and every time I retrieve the objects, I am writing a filter. below is the code :

My `models.py`

```
class Crew(models.Model):
    crew_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    crew_code = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, unique=True)
    crew_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    crew_password = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

My `views.py` :

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_crews(request):
    c = Crew.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    serializer = CrewSerializer(c, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: What's wrong with this method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write [custom model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset):

```
class IsActiveManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(IsActiveManager, self).get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)

class Crew(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = IsActiveManager()
```

Now `Crew.objects.all()` will return only is_active record.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wanted. but this also removes all the inactive objects/entries in the admin listing. I need to display all the objects in the admin listing. But filter only in the apis.

Comment: @SahanaPrabhakar you are welcome! You can set two managers for models. `objects = models.Manager() 
    active_objects = IsActiveManager()` so when you need only active records you can use `Crew.active_objects.all()`

Answer (score 2):

You can write a mixin in mixin.py file something like this

```
class TimeFieldsMixin(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, db_index=True)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

And Import this in your models like this:

```
class User(TimeFieldsMixin):
     // model fields
```

This will add this fields by default wherever you use this mixin.

Let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: I did understand this. My question was actually to filter only active fields. But this will save my time a lot. I will not have to write `is_active` field for every model. thanks.

Comment: Ah ok i understood it differently.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if you have additional Model Managers:

The first manager listed in the model class definition is the one that is used for the admin site and a number of other operations.